# Build action for a image in C# windows serivce

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am working with a Solution that contains many different projects. My project in particular is in charge of sending a email notification. I've created a EmailTemplate.cs that is used to generate the email. In this EmailTemplate.cs I use 2 images when sending the email.

This Windows-Service gets deployed to different environments, PROD,STG,DEV.
We also use Jenkins for our CI/CD.

I ran into a scenario were the images were not being loaded correctly because when the service got deployed the images were not part of the Jenkins file to include the images to the output directory.

I know I can update the Jenkins file to copy the images to the output directory, and change the Build Action of the image to Content and Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always. But i am hesitant to do so.

My question is what is ideal/ best practice for this scenario of including images with the solution.

I read about embedded resource for the image but all the articles are dated/old and want to know what is best for this age.

I read about embedded resource for the image but all the articles are dated/old and want to know what is best for this age.

I have already changed the Build Action to Content and Copy to Output directory to Always. Which works but i do not like the idea of copying the images the the output directory.

```
public struct EmailTemplate
    {
        public const string Html =
            @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset=""utf-8"" />
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table width = ""650px"" height=""550px"" style=""border-color: #3399ff; border-width:4px"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"">
        <tr style = ""border-style: hidden"" >
            <td align=""center"" style=""background-color:white"">
               <span style = ""font-size:25px;"" >
                    <span>
                        <img id=""mediaShuttleLogo""src=""mediashuttleLogo"">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align=""center"" style=""border-style: hidden"">
            <td>
                <br />
                <span style=""color: #3399ff; font-family:Calibri"" > RequesterEmail has sent you content via Media Shuttle.</span>
                <br />
                <span>
                    <img id = ""downloadIcon""
                         src=""downloadImage""
                         style='border-bottom-width:0in;border-left-width:0in;border-right-width:0in;border-top-width:0in;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:6px'>
                </span>
                <div class=""top-rectangle""></div>
                <div class=""arrow-down""></div>
                <br />
                <a href = ""EmailDownloadLink"" id=""EmailDownloadLink"" >
                    Click here to download
                </a>
                <br />
                <br />
                <span style = ""font-size:15px; font-family:Calibri"" > Download link will expire after first download. </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For images in emails they really should be links to images on the internet. Many email clients don't show images you have to "download pictures".

Using images online also allows you to track the number of people who read the email by tracking the hits to the image.

If you were building a Winforms/Service app I'd recommend the Copy To Output or as embedded resources.

If it's a Website you would include the 'compressed for web' images with the site or host them on a CDN.

For mobile apps if it's HTML app host images on web. If it's a native mobile app (not photo sharing) embed the images in the exe.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, yes this is a Service that is deployed to different environments. I realize i can do Copy To Output or embedded resource but wondering what is best so that the when Jenkins builds all the dlls/exe I will not have to worry about if the image actually was copied, but instead of the dlls/exe. Or what is best practice for this scenario.

Comment: If you have Copy To Output, in your Jenkins job copy everything from the bin folder or if you only want to copy DLL/exe then embed the resources. It's up to you, but as a rule of thumb don't bloat your exe with gigantic images in that case don't put them as embedded resources.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was able to embed both images into the exe.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="MediaShuttleEmail\Images\email-download-button.png" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="MediaShuttleEmail\Images\mediashuttle-logo.png" />
```

Then in the EmailTemplate.cs I updated the way to read the embedded images.

For the "src" value, you need to point it at the Content-Id of the LinkedResource image. This is done by using the syntax  The "src=cid:" part is required for the email client to recognize the  tag as an embedded image, while the "whatever" part is the actual Content-Id of the LinkedResource image.  This will instruct the mail client to find an embedded image named "whatever" and display the contents *without* making a http:// request.

Then I need to read the embedded images from the assembly:

```
 private static Stream GetMSLogoAssembly()
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        Type typeOf = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        Assembly assm = typeOf.Assembly;
        foreach (var resourceName in assm.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (resourceName.Contains("mediashuttle-logo.png"))
            {
                stream = assm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
            }
        }
        return stream;
    }

    private static Stream GetDownloadArrowAssembly()
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        Type typeOf = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        Assembly assm = typeOf.Assembly;
        foreach (var resourceName in assm.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (resourceName.Contains("email-download-button.png"))
            {
                stream = assm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
            }
        }
        return stream;
    }
```

Then I need to create image resource from image path using LinkedResource:

```
string htmlBody = MailText;
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, "text/html");

            // create image resource from image path using LinkedResource 
            // LinkedResource class represents an embedded external resource in email, ex: a image
            LinkedResource msLogoImageResource = new LinkedResource(GetMSLogoAssembly(), contentType)
            {
                ContentId = "msLogoImage",
                TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
            };
            LinkedResource downloadArrowImageResource = new LinkedResource(GetDownloadArrowAssembly(), contentType)
            {
                ContentId = "downloadArrowImage",
                TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
            };

            // adding the images linked to htmlView...
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(msLogoImageResource);
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(downloadArrowImageResource);

            string subjectMessage = $"Content available for download at MediaShuttle. {subject}";
            MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage(From, To)
            {
                Subject = subjectMessage,
                Body = MailText,
                Priority = MailPriority.Normal,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };

            emailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(emailServer);
            smtpClient.Send(emailMessage);
```

After doing all this, I no longer need to worry about ensuring the images are copied to any directory when deploying.